# Async/Await call doesn't return. Forcing sync does

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-web-api

I've got a problem with Async/Await that I can't get my head around.

The code below is inside a WebAPI controller:

This works ( forcing Sync through `.Result` )

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(long id)
{
    var distribution = this.Service.GetById(id).Result;
    var result = distribution == null ?
            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) :
            Request.CreateResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                    distribution.AsViewModel(identity));
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't ( using await )

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(long id)
{
    var distribution = await this.Service.GetById(id);
    var result = distribution == null ?
            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) : 
            Request.CreateResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                    distribution.AsViewModel(identity));
    return result;
}
```

Here are a few observations and extra information:

- The service talks to a repository which is on EF6 and gets stuff out
  of the database `async` ( `.SingleOrDefaultAsync()` ).
- The angular service fires the request and it just remains pending in network tab. Also if you navigate to the page, you get nothing. Other times you don't reach the line after await and nothing happens. No exceptions either.
- If I debug the service (having the `await` keyword in place) and I step through the
  code it sometimes 'just works' and I get the data from the database
  and all is good.
- Service and DataContext are injected using Ninject's `InRequestScope()`

And the weirdest thing is that I could have sworn this worked when I released it last sprint. Any ideas how I can go about fixing this thing?

**EDIT**

Here's the service:

```
public Task<Distribution> GetById(long id)
{
    return this._distributionRepository.GetById(id);
}
```

And here's the repository:

```
public Task<Distribution> GetById(long id)
{
    return this.DataContext.Distributions.SingleAsync(d => d.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting the code in your post - it's harder to read at the moment than it needs to be - it's further to the right than necessary, and you've got an extra level of indentation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Are you saying `await this.Service.GetById(id)` is hanging?

Comment: Yes, Indeed - so when I step through the code, during the await ... call, I'm returned to the browser ( thread is released? ), however, it never picks it up again to when the data is returned. If you force it to run sync, I wait in the Visual Studio until data comes in and the debugger moves to the next line.

Comment: I'm really disappointed in the downvotes. I've got a real problem, I did Google + try to find out how to solve this, I made an effort to describe it properly and provide code samples. OK, so indentation may not have been optimal, but downvoting seems a little harsh too.

Comment: Could you please add the code for `GetById`?

Comment: So, you are saying, sometimes `this.Service.GetById(id)` doesn't return when awaited? How long have you waited? I think the implementation of `Service`, in relation to `GetById` is the key to finding your problem. I see nothing functionally wrong with the `Get` implementation on your controller but would prefer an `if` block instead of the ternary operator.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - sure I will. Give me a couple of minutes. It's a Task all the way down and then somehing like return DataContext.Distributions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id).

Comment: add CancellationToken to request, wrap everything in try/catch. maybe exception is happening in async thread

Comment: @unarity - wrapped in try/catch, but didn't catch anything.

Comment: In order to `await this.Service.GetById(id);`, `GetById(id)` should be declared `async`. In your case it is not `public Task<Distribution> GetById(long id)`. Make it [all way down async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: @spike: Have you got `httpRuntime.targetFramework` set to `4.5` in your `web.config`?

Comment: @StephenCleary It wasn't there, I added it, but it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: @spike: Also ensure that you are compiling for the .NET 4.5 framework.

Comment: Done - I immediately checked that too. Confirmed that Target framework is 4.5. Thanks @StephenCleary

Comment: @spike: In that case, what type is `SynchronizationContext.Current` when your `async` method is running?

Comment: @StephenCleary AspNetSynchronizationContext - please note: I haven't implemented the proposed solution below. I've just got one 'await' at the moment and that's in the controller.

Comment: @spike: Can you create a minimal repro?

Comment: OK - I'll try that tonight. @StephenCleary Although I'm pretty sure I won't be able to do that, since my code should just work IMHO. I think it's something in the .config (as you proposed) or some other setting that was changed by the team.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I know you're stackOverflow C# Wizzard ( .NET Rocks! ) - do you think the proposed answer is a good approach ( placing async await  in all application tiers ) ?

Comment: @spike: Well, you probably want to have asynchrony in some form or other all the way down - whether that means `async` methods or not is a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, but that's the case, right? At the lowest level I've got the GetSingleOrDefaultAsync() and I'm returning that task. I'm awaiting it only at the top level, so that there's just one state machine, namely for the stuff in the controller. Or am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Comment: I honestly haven't followed this question all the way through - I only commented on the lack of formatting. But if you're using `.Result`, that's still synchronous...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, to `await` on `this.Service.GetById(id)` you should declare `GetById` method `async`, and [all the way down it should be `async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).
So your code should be something like this

**Controller**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(long id)
{
    var distribution = await this.Service.GetByIdAsync(id);
    var result = distribution == null ?
            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) :
            Request.CreateResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.OK, 
                    distribution.AsViewModel(identity));
    return result;
}
```

**Service**

```
public async Task<Distribution> GetByIdAsync(long id)
{
    return await this._distributionRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public async Task<Distribution> GetByIdAsync(long id)
{
    return await this.DataContext.Distributions.SingleAsync(d => d.Id == id);
}
```

I would also suggest to follow `async` method convention and add `async` to your async methods, so you should rename `GetById` method to `GetByIdAsync` in your *Service* and *Repository*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this but this would change the way I think about async/await. I thought the async keyword causes the compiler to build a statemachine arount that method. I want the compiler to do that for only 1 method and that's the one in the ApiController. From the others I expect to get a task which is then awaited. Also, I'm not sure the article you refer to means placing async in all the methods when they talk about 'async all the way down'. But like I said, I'll look into it and get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: There's rarely any point in making a method `async` if it's just going to use `return await ...`. You might as well just declare the method without `async`, and just return `this._distributionRepository.GetByIdAsync(id)` (etc)